# How to display User Activity Information in each subsite for a site collection in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-usage, logs

I am trying to capture when did users last used the subsite within a site collection. How do i gather that information with automated way rather than manual looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that we cannot display the information about who and when log into the site by OOB mothed in the modern page.

There are two workarounds.

1. Display the site usage page in the modern page.

To access the site usage page, go to site contents->site usage.
[image]

Then edit the modern page->click “Embed” like the picture below->Add the iframe code below.

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="siteusageURL"></iframe>
```

[image]

2. Add the “Google analysis in the modern page.  For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[How to add Google Analytics to the Modern SharePoint.](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2017/12/21/how-to-add-google-analytics-to-the-modern-sharepoint/)

[Deploy Google Analytics globally on modern SharePoint.](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2019/02/10/deploy-google-analytics-globally-on-modern-sharepoint/)

Comment: Do we have quick powershell script to handle this?